# Answering your own question within the question

Tags: discussion

I just came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40458546/how-do-i-run-a-db-select-and-get-the-result-in-iex) question. The asker has found the answer themselves and edited the question with the solution. Usually under these circumstances, the person would add an actual answer to their question.

I am unsure how something like this should be handled.

My only thought was that I could edit the question to remove the answer and add it as an actual answer for the question as a community wiki. My hesitation in doing this is that if I came across this question before the answer edit, I most likely would have attempted to flag it as low quality because the code that they have there is invalid.

So, I was just wondering what the broader community thinks should be done in a scenario like this.

Comment: I think this isn't a complete duplicate and actually prompts a very validate question about the quality of the original question. Whilst the accepted answer in the proposed duplicate suggests rolling it back, in this case the question would therefore look to be low quality and might end up being cited in the future as "Why was my question closed when this one wasn't?" etc.